# Receiving double free or corruption (top) when closing a pipe?

Tags: c++, c, memory, gdb, valgrind

So I have an array of n streams that I open with pipes, but using gdb, I found that the program fails when I try to close either the stream or the write end of the pipes.  I can write to the pipes just fine, but closing them doesn't work.  I ran valgrind on the program and all it did was print out

```
==4241== Warning: invalid file descriptor -1 in syscall read()
```

over and over again.  Here is the code in question and error output.  If any more info is needed please let me know and I will try to provide it. Thanks everyone.

```
191                 /*closes unused pipes and open streams to sorting processes*/
192                 for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
193                         close(parse2sortPipes[i][READ]);
194                         close(sort2outputPipes[i][READ]);
195                         close(sort2outputPipes[i][WRITE]);
196                         outStreams[i] = fdopen(parse2sortPipes[i][WRITE], "w");
197                 }
198 
199                 while (getWord(fstream, wBuf) != -1) {
200                         if (i == n) {
201                                 i = 0;
202                         }
203                         fputs(wBuf, outStreams[i]);
204                         fputc('\n', outStreams[i]);
205                         i++;
206                 }
207 
208 
209 
210                 for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
211                         fflush(outStreams[i]);
212                         fclose(outStreams[i]); //this is where it fails
213                         close(parse2sortPipes[i][WRITE]);
214                 }
215 


*** Error in `..../xxx': double free or corruption (top): 0x0000000000603250 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
208         for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x80a46)[0x7ffff7a92a46]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(fclose+0x14d)[0x7ffff7a80a6d]
/home/user/school/cs/assignments/hw3/xxx[0x401477]
/home/user/school/cs/assignments/hw3/xxx[0x400ce7]
(gdb) /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7ffff7a33ea5]
/home/user/school/cs/assignments/hw3/xxx[0x400b39]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00402000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 12588471                           /home/daniel/school/cs311/assignments/hw3/xxx
00601000-00602000 r--p 00001000 08:06 12588471                           /home/daniel/school/cs311/assignments/hw3/xxx
00602000-00603000 rw-p 00002000 08:06 12588471                           /home/daniel/school/cs311/assignments/hw3/xxx
00603000-00624000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7ffff77fc000-7ffff7810000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 3149442                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7ffff7810000-7ffff7a10000 ---p 00014000 08:06 3149442                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7ffff7a10000-7ffff7a11000 r--p 00014000 08:06 3149442                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7ffff7a11000-7ffff7a12000 rw-p 00015000 08:06 3149442                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7ffff7a12000-7ffff7bd0000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 3149417                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so
7ffff7bd0000-7ffff7dcf000 ---p 001be000 08:06 3149417                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so
7ffff7dcf000-7ffff7dd3000 r--p 001bd000 08:06 3149417                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so
7ffff7dd3000-7ffff7dd5000 rw-p 001c1000 08:06 3149417                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so
7ffff7dd5000-7ffff7dda000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff7dda000-7ffff7dfd000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 3149393                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so
7ffff7fd7000-7ffff7fda000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff7ff6000-7ffff7ff8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff7ff8000-7ffff7ffa000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff7ffa000-7ffff7ffc000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
7ffff7ffc000-7ffff7ffd000 r--p 00022000 08:06 3149393                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so
7ffff7ffd000-7ffff7fff000 rw-p 00023000 08:06 3149393                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so
7ffffffde000-7ffffffff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fclose` will close the underlying file descriptor, so don't call `close` afterwards.

Comment: This didn't fix the problem, but I didn't know this before.  Thank you